# Enumerate TypeScript string literals

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to loop over the values of a TypeScript string literal?

```
type category = "foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "xyzzy"

for (c in category) {
    // ... do something with each category
}
```

I currently have something like this:

```
let cat: category = ...

switch (cat) {
    case "foo":
    default:
        process("foo")
        break

    case "bar":
        process("bar")
        break

    case "baz":
        process("baz")
        break

    case "xyzzy":
        process("xyzzy")
        break
}
```

but I would rather use something like

```
let others: category = []
for (c in category) {      // Iterate over possible category values
    if (c !== "foo") others.push(c)
}

if (others.indexOf(cat) >= 0) {
    process(cat)
} else {
    process("foo")
}
```

Comment: `let others: category = ["foo" , "bar" , "baz" , "xyzzy"]`

Comment: I was trying to find a DRY way to keep the categories in one place and not have to repeat them in the definition of `others`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With typescript 2.1 and [keyof type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), it's possible to do it the other way round - you can define an object with necessary keys, and get union type of all the keys using `keyof`:

```
let categoryKeys = {foo: '', bar: '', baz: '', xyzzy: ''}; // values do not matter

type category = keyof typeof categoryKeys;

let x: category = 'foo'; // ok
let z: category = 'z'; //  error TS2322: Type '"z"' is not assignable 
                       // to type '"foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "xyzzy"'.

console.log(Object.keys(categoryKeys)); // prints [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'xyzzy' ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to convince the compiler that Object.keys(categoryKeys) has type category[] and not just string[]. I would really like to be able to iterate over Object.keys(categoryKeys) and use the elements as argument to a function that requires something of type category.

Answer (score 4):

This is the type declaration.

```
type category = "foo" | "bar" | "baz" | "xyzzy"
```

TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript that has no types.
Type in the TypeScript is just an information for transpiler about possible certain values (in this case). And type declaration is not compiled into any real runtime JavaScript object.
Thus you can not iterate through it, but you can use it in switch construction.

Comment: Having said that, it's technically possible for the compiler to convert some special syntax (`arrayof category`?) into a literal array (`["foo", "bar", ...]`) at compile time, but there is definitely no such feature at the moment, and it might be argued that this doesn't really fit with typescript's principles.